# Number of testers who gave up don't match with the number testers in the path (Maze app)

Tags: usability-testing, test

In the Maze app, the number of users shown in 'Give-up / Bounce' tab is 60:

[image: Number of users in 'Give-up' tab]

Although, the number of users shown on the first screen of the prototype is 28.
Does that mean that 60 users gave up in the mission screen before the initial page of the prototype?

[image]

Comment: Just discovered that Maze creates different "paths" for each amount of testers, so that means 28 testers took the same path while doing this task, but others could do the same task with a different path (when you sum all the paths, the numbers will match)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Maze before, but according to the screenshot it seems like there were 60 participants recruited for the click/impression test, and because 40.54% gave up it leaves 28 participants that have completed the test.